# Where should I place my Vaadin 10+ static files?

Tags: spring, polymer, vaadin, stylesheet, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin 10-14, where should I place my static files, such as CSS, JavaScript, and Polymer templates? How about static files such as images?

Also, how do I import these files in Vaadin? Is there a difference between Vaadin 14 with npm and Vaadin 10-13 with bower?

Comment: Similar: [*Where to put data or config files loaded by my Java code when web app launches in a Vaadin 14 web app driven by Maven*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59996594/642706)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

All paths are relative to the project root, e.g. where the `pom.xml` file is located in a Maven project.

JavaScript imported using `@JsModule` uses [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Among other things, this means that global variables must be defined on the `window` object, `window.x = ...`, instead of just `x = ...`.

---

### Vaadin 14 with npm

#### Non-Spring Boot projects (war packaging)

- CSS files

  - `@CssImport("./my-styles/styles.css")`<sup>[1]</sup>
  - `/frontend/my-styles/styles.css`
- JavaScript and Polymer templates

  - `@JsModule("./src/my-script.js")`<sup>[1]</sup>
  - `/frontend/src/my-script.js`
- Static files, e.g. images

  - `new Image("img/flower.jpg", "A flower")`
  - `/src/main/webapp/img/flower.jpg`

#### Spring Boot projects (jar packaging)

- CSS files

  - `@CssImport("./my-styles/styles.css")`<sup>[1]</sup>
  - `/frontend/my-styles/styles.css`
- JavaScript and Polymer templates

  - `@JsModule("./src/my-script.js")`<sup>[1]</sup>
  - `/frontend/src/my-script.js`
- Static files, e.g. images

  - `new Image("img/flower.jpg", "A flower")`
  - `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/img/flower.jpg`

#### Add-ons (jar packaging)

- CSS files

  - `@CssImport("./my-styles/styles.css")`<sup>[1]</sup>
  - `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/my-styles/styles.css`
- JavaScript and Polymer templates

  - `@JsModule("./src/my-script.js")`<sup>[1]</sup>
  - `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/src/my-script.js`
- Static files, e.g. images

  - `new Image("img/flower.jpg", "A flower")`
  - `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/img/flower.jpg`

---

### Vaadin 10-13, Vaadin 14 in compatibility mode

#### Non-Spring Boot projects (war packaging)

- CSS files

  - `@StyleSheet("css/styles.css")`<sup>[2]</sup>
  - `/src/main/webapp/frontend/css/styles.css`
- Polymer templates, custom-style and dom-module styles

  - `@HtmlImport("src/template.html")`
  - `/src/main/webapp/frontend/src/template.html`
- JavaScript

  - `@JavaScript("js/script.js")`<sup>[3]</sup>
  - `/src/main/webapp/frontend/js/script.js`
- Static files, e.g. images

  - `new Image("img/flower.jpg", "A flower")`
  - `/src/main/webapp/img/flower.jpg`

#### Spring Boot projects and add-ons (jar packaging)

- CSS files

  - `@StyleSheet("css/styles.css")`<sup>[2]</sup>
  - `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/css/styles.css`
- Polymer templates, custom-style and dom-module styles

  - `@HtmlImport("src/template.html")`
  - `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/src/template.html`
- JavaScript

  - `@JavaScript("js/script.js")`<sup>[3]</sup>
  - `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/js/script.js`
- Static files, e.g. images

  - `new Image("img/flower.jpg", "A flower")`
  - `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/img/flower.jpg`

---

### Footnotes

<sup>[1]</sup> The `@JsModule` and `@CssImport` annotations can also be used for importing from an npm package. In this case, the path is defined as `@JsModule("@polymer/paper-input")` or `@CssImport("some-package/style.css")`. **Paths referring to the local frontend directory should be prefixed with `./`**

<sup>[2]</sup> The `@StyleSheet` annotation can also be used in Vaadin 14 with npm. The same paths as in V10-V13 can be used, including the `context://` protocol `@StyleSheet("context://style.css")`, which resolves the path relative to the context path of the web application, like other static files. **Styles included this way may cause issues with web components**.

<sup>[3]</sup> The `@JavaScript` annotation can also be used in Vaadin 14 with npm. **The V14 `/frontend` folder should then be used**,.

Comment: Is there a list for the file locations regarding a PWA (worker, manifest, etc.)?

Comment: @mkemmerz At least the service worker is generated on startup. If you want to override it or want more info, check out the documentation https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/pwa/tutorial-pwa-introduction.html. In particular the "PWA Service Worker" and "PWA Web App Manfiest" subpages might be useful to you.

Comment: Where to store simple data files loaded when the web app launches, such as JSON/XML/CSV files? I mean files that are accessed by my Java code, never served to web browsers.

Comment: @BasilBourque You can put it in `src/main/resources` and access it e.g. with `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myfile.txt")`, the leading slash is important.

Answer (score 6):

@Tazavoo 's answer has been added to the official Vaadin documentation:

[Vaadin Resource Cheat sheet](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/loading-resources#resource-cheat-sheet)

I just wanted to put it here because I hope this will stay updated in the future. Please forgive me that I don't post the tables here but this answer will run over otherwise.

Comment: Reference to `Vaadin 15` should be changed to `Vaadin Latest`, and the link should be https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/advanced/loading-resources#resource-cheat-sheet
Vaadin 15 isn't supported anyways and the user will be redirected to latest.

Answer (score 2):

While Erik Lumme's answer is basically correct, I would like to share my experience about java script loading in a vaadin23 spring boot project, packaged as war. There are subtle differences about how the path must be indicated.

@JsModule:

- path prefixed by "./": The path must be relative to the "frontend" folder
- path without prefix: The path must be relative to the "node_modules" folder (maintained by npm).

Loading a java script by Page.addJavaScript(): The path must be relative to the root of the deployed application (in tomcat), rsp. to "src/main/webapp" in the project source.

Answer (score 0):

We have shared resources of several Vaadin 14 modules like this:

- маke common directory form project root `/resources/static`
- route request there via nginx at prod and via Spring at local dev

  ```
  public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

     @Override
     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
       .addResourceLocations("file:./resources/static/")
       .setCachePeriod(3600);
       registry.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
  ```

  }
- for css remove all

  ```
  @CssImport("./styles/root/global-styles.css")
  ```

and put in MainView (`@Route` view), see https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/importing-style-sheets:

```
   @StyleSheet("/static/css/global-styles.css")
```

- for images put it to css

  ```
  .plus-btn {
     background: url("../static/icons/plus.svg") no-repeat center;
  }
  ```