# vaadin css file not found

Tags: java, css, intellij-idea, vaadin

I am kinda new to Vaadin and I use vaadin 13.0.13. I tried to refactor some code using the css file i created and put in `src/main/resources/com/example/demo`.
I followed the documentation [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/importing-dependencies/tutorial-include-css.html). However as you can see on the following picture, it seems vaadin does not read that file.

> Is there a particular reason ? What should I do to add a css file in
>   my vaadin/spring project ?

Thanks.

[image: picture1]

Comment: Could you please add your `@StyleSheet` annotation definition? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment in documentation you linked:

> Probably the place where it should be added same as for v10-v13 so: Non-Spring project: /src/main/webapp/frontend Spring project: /src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend

So, depending on your project, it's either:

- `/src/main/webapp/frontend` (Non-spring)
- `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend` (Spring project)

A good overview of right locations for static resources could be found here [Where should I place my Vaadin 10+ static files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57553973/where-should-i-place-my-vaadin-10-static-files/57553974#57553974)
The section you should check is `Vaadin 10-13, Vaadin 14 in compatibility mode`

Comment: @StyleSheet("style.css")
Non-Spring project: /src/main/webapp/frontend
Spring project: /src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend.

It seems that you should not give the full path, now it works. Thanks !