# Images to show with Vaadin 14

Tags: java, image, upload, vaadin, vaadin14

I'm writing this post because I need some help.
I'm having trouble display an image depending on a specific path in my App.

Basically what it's doing: I have a module named Sector, and each Sector can have an image related to it. When I use the Upload component of Vaadin, I save the path of the image to a table in my database so that it can display the picture chosen before.

The actual path of the image is weird, it seems that Vaadin copies the image to a dynamic random folder. It seems logical that it can't use the actual path of the image.

But here's the problem: The path is well entered in the Database, but when I reload the page (F5), Vaadin can't shows the image anymore. Which upsets me since it should display it well.

The path that Vaadin creates with the uploaded image : VAADIN/dynamic/resource/2/c1ef7b9d-8f2b-4354-a97e-fe1fd4e868e7/551434.jpg

I can put some code if it can help.

The screenshots show what it's doing once I'm refreshing the browser page.

[The image is being uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5ePH.jpg)

[After refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szL6m.png)

Here is the part of the code where I handle the upload image:

```
upload.addSucceededListener(e -> {
            Component component = createComponent(e.getMIMEType(),
                    e.getFileName(), buffer.getInputStream());
            showOutput(e.getFileName(), component, output);
            //imgUpload = (Image) component;
            InputStream inputStream = buffer.getInputStream();
            targetFile = new File(PATH + currentProjetId + "\\secteur" + currentSecId + "\\photoSec.png");
            try {
                FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, targetFile);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Notification.show("Error");
            }
            System.out.println("PATH : " + targetFile.getPath());
        });
```

Comment: You have to store the uploaded image. This is just a temporary URL

Comment: Can you modify the question and share the code of how you're handling the upload?

Comment: I've added the part of the code where I handle the upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using an in-memory resource that's discarded when you refresh the view. You have to take the contents of the file and save it in a file inside a directory in the server's file system. Here's an example:

```
FileBuffer receiver = new FileBuffer();
Upload upload = new Upload(receiver);
upload.setAcceptedFileTypes("text/plain");
upload.addSucceededListener(event -> {
    try {
      InputStream in = receiver.getInputStream();
      File tempFile = receiver.getFileData().getFile();
      File destFile = new File("/some/directory/" + event.getFileName());
      FileUtils.moveFile(tempFile, destFile);
      
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Notification.show("Error").
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've succeeded in saving the image into a specific folder inside the app directory (actualy it's in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/photos). I read on that  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57553973/where-should-i-place-my-vaadin-10-static-files/57553974#57553974) that it was the place for static images.
But I can't create an Image out of that path now. It's like it doesn't know where to look for the image.

I can put some screens about the path and how I create the image if it helps you understand it.

I'm sorry if my english isn't great.

Comment: During project compilation `src/main/resources` is copied to the `target/classes` folder (in this case to `target/classes/META-INF/resources/photos`) so during execution you won't get the uploaded file as a resource through there. The file should be stored somewhere else on the file system and loaded from there and made into a `StreamResource` for serving during execution.

Comment: Okay, it's a bit blurry for me, would it be possible to have an example using the `StreamResource` thing?
Because, from what I understand, I can't create an image from the copied File because it's not stored at a correct place. But where and how should I store it?

Comment: The target file could be anywhere on the disk and then you can read it to a inputStream `File imageFile = new File("my/downloaded/file.jgp");` -> `InputStream targetStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(imageFile);` that is then used for the 
[StreamResource](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-dynamic-content/#using-streamresource)

Comment: Okay so if I understand correctly:
 - When the user uploads an image, I copy the file to a directory `/home/user/photos` as an example.
- I store the path of the File in my Database
- When he goes to the view where I need to display the image: I create an `InputStream` with the image, to then use `StreamResource` to display the content
Is that it?

And if you know it, could you explain to me how to use that  `StreamResource` ?

Thanks by the way.

Comment: Just look at the [documentation link](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-dynamic-content#using-streamresource) and for instance at the [upload demo creating an image](https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/blob/1c9206f420eb76d65a3131ee464ae99c5595b2a3/vaadin-upload-flow-parent/vaadin-upload-flow-demo/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/upload/demo/UploadView.java#L273)

Comment: You can find another example at https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-image

Comment: Okay, I've succeeded in doing what I wanted.
The fact is that I found a link about Vaadin 11, and it works on Vaadin 14.
[Here](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17313780/vaadin-11-how-to-load-image-from-imputstream) it is.
Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Good to hear! Thanks for sharing the rest of the solution. If the answer was useful, can you mark it as accepted, please?