# Image component not displaying in Vaadin Flow application

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin22

I have a view in my Vaadin Flow Application called HomeView. I am attempting to add an Image component called **logo.png** to this view to display it on the home page. The code for HomeView looks like so:

```
package ymca.tracker.application.views.home;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H2;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Image;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

@PageTitle("Home")
@Route(value = "home")
public class HomeView extends VerticalLayout {

    public HomeView() {
        setSpacing(false);

        add(new H2("Welcome!"));
        add(new Image("frontend/images/logo.png", ""));

        setSizeFull(); setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);
    setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);
    getStyle().set("text-align", "center");
    }
}
```

I have verified the file path is correct as well as the name and type of the file. I have tried adding alternate text but the image still does not display. Currently, an icon is emplaced instead of the actual image I want displayed. See below:

[image]

I've tried directly placing the file in the frontend folder as well, with no luck either. Not sure what the issue could be here as this seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I place my Vaadin 10+ static files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57553973/where-should-i-place-my-vaadin-10-static-files)

Comment: @cfrick Looking over this post, I still don't really see a solid solution for my issue. I understand what the post was getting at, but regardless of where the image is placed in the frontend directory, it refuses to display.

Comment: You are using `frontend` in your `new Image(...)`.

Comment: This is the official Resources cheat sheet: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/advanced/loading-resources/#resource-cheat-sheet.

Comment: If you do `new Image("img/flower.jpg", "A flower")` then the file location should be `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/img/flower.jpg` in Spring Boot project, or `/src/main/webapp/img/flower.jpg` in plain Java projects.