# Static resouces not loading after packaging JAR of Vaadin 14 app

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using Spring Boot for a Vaadin Flow 14 app and when I package into a JAR using `mvn clean package -Pproduction` and run it using `java -jar app.jar` it doesn't show any images or fonts, however the CSS works.

Running the app in dev mode works perfectly, and even running it with `mvn spring-boot:run -Pproduction` works perfectly. The problem is after packaging into a JAR.

I haven't updated anything or change any major files, I just change some functions in java classes and now after packaging the issues are showing, it wasn't like this a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I place my Vaadin 10+ static files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57553973/where-should-i-place-my-vaadin-10-static-files)

Comment: Managed to make it work by updating to the latest vaadin, I had another couple of issues with I managed those as well. I don't know if this could work, but doesn't hurt to update to the latest